# Windows NGINX reverse proxy issues proxy from http to https or advice me with config file

Tags: nginx

I have Windows Server with `IP 10.0.0.5`

Also added Firewall inbound Rules port 80,443,9444

This `IP 100.100.50.50` external provided some company and connected with VPN tunnel
with this Windows Server `IP 10.0.0.5`

From manual this company I should add to hostsfile
In Windows server in hosts file I add this

100.100.50.50 someservice.com
127.0.0.1     loc.someservice.com

Now in windows server I install insomnia and following manual
I set credentials try post like this

```
post https://someservice.com:9444/oauth2/token
```

In Windows Server I get result success I mean I get token etc…

Now I want to try this post from another local windows machine

I install nginx in windows server

here my config

```
server {    
    listen 80; 
    listen 9444; 
    server_name loc.someservice.com:9444;
    location / {
     proxy_pass someservice.com:9444;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header Host someservice.com;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
     proxy_ssl_name $host;
     proxy_ssl_server_name on;
     proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
   } 
 }
```

In my local machine

I set hosts IP windows server

```
10.0.0.5 loc.someservice.com
```

I post in my local machine via Insomnia like this

```
post http://loc.someservice.com:9444/oauth2/token
```

Get error

```
   Bad request 400
```

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: It looks like everyting you wrote is workig, because the webserver is working. When the webservice is returning `400` check the webservice and its logs.